# The Tabs in TabLayout cover the Fragment

Tags: android-tablayout

The Tabs cover the Fragment's top. I want the Fragment to reduce its height and go down a little to show the whole Fragment's layout.

This is how I make the Tabs:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabIconTintMode="src_over"
    app:tabMode="fixed"

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tab3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

And here is the code:

```
    tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    fragments = getFragments();//To get all the fragments under ViewPager
    pagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.mainViewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `TabLayout` with `ViewPager`, try adding the attribute `app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"`

Or, add the attribute `layout_below=YOUR_APP_BAR_ID` to your `TabsLayout`